# C++ Variable de tipo objeto suma declarada como puntero, al pasar valores al constructor este me devuelve un valor de resultado=-1163005939

Tags: c++

Me pasa el siguiente problema, cuando intento pasar los valores al constructor como se ve en el código, al llamar el método resultado este me devuelve un valor=-1163005939 entonces es como si los datos que se pasaran al constructor de la manera que esta , no fueran correctos.

Código de la función principal `main`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "suma1.h" // ahora incluimos en la cabecera el archivo suma1.h

using namespace std;

int main(){
    suma1 *Objetosuma; // declarando la variable puntero tipo suma
    int n1, n2;
    cout<<"Digite el primer numero"<<endl;
    cin>>n1;
    cout<<"Digite el segundo numero"<<endl;
    cin>>n2;
    Objetosuma=new suma1(n1,n2);
    Objetosuma->MostrarResultado();

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Código de la clase suma1.h

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class suma1{  
private:
    int numero1,numero2,resultado;
public:
    suma1(int n1,int n2) // por puntero
    {
        this->numero1 = n1;
        this->numero2 = n2;
    }

    void OperacionSuma(){
        this->resultado =this->numero1+this->numero2;
    }

    void MostrarResultado(){
        cout<<"El resultado es "<<this->resultado<<endl;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que `suma1::resultado` no se inicializa en el constructor de `suma1` ni se le da valor en toda la ejecución (porque no llamas `suma1::OperacionSuma`) esta variable miembro se queda con un valor indeterminado, que es ese valor negativo que ves.

Muy probablemente querías hacer esto:

```
Objetosuma=new suma1(n1,n2);
Objetosuma->OperacionSuma(); // Te falta hacer la operación
Objetosuma->MostrarResultado();
```

Si quieres evitar el problema de los valores extraños, inicializa las variables miembro:

```
class suma1{  
private:
    int numero1 = 0, numero2 = 0, resultado = 0; // Valores iniciales
public:
    suma1(int n1, int n2)
    {
        numero1 = n1; // No es necesario 'this'.
        numero2 = n2; // No es necesario 'this'.
    }

    void OperacionSuma(){
        resultado = numero1 + numero2; // No es necesario 'this'.
    }

    void MostrarResultado(){
        cout<<"El resultado es "<<resultado<<endl; // No es necesario 'this'.
    }
};
```

Comment: si, lo intente de esa manera, pero tambien hay un detalle y es que ahora da 0 como resultado

Comment: Probablemente sigas sin llamar primero a la función ```OperacionSuma()``` antes de ```MostrarResultado()```

Comment: Entiendo el punto, pero no me explique desde el principio, segun la tarea es que debo de pasar los valores de las variables por parametros al constructor y desde el metodo                                                 OperacionSuma()        se debe hacer el proceso, o sera que yo estoy mal

Comment: Cuando creas un objeto de la clase suma, el constructor coge los parámetros y los asigna a los miembros ```numero1``` y ```numero2``` , pero ningún valor a ```resultado```, por lo que este miembro vale su valor por defecto, que es 0 en el momento en el que se crea la clase. (Antes era basura, cuando no inicializabas). Pero si no llamas en ningún momento al método ```OperacionSuma()``` el valor de ```resultado``` nunca se actualizará.

Comment: @CarlosPeralta no es verdad que de 0 como resultado, yo he probado [el código tal y como lo he propuesto y funciona](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6vN3Q39f6Znh1MLL).

Comment: Si tienes razon, ya esta respuesta me ayudo mucho a entender , si funciona a la perfeccion , muchas gracias por su ayuda